# Exceptions connecting to MongoDB Replica Set hosted inside Kubernetes with bitnami Helm chart

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, bitnami

We experienced some problems (timeout and notPrimary Exceptions) if we tried connecting to a MongoDB Replica Set hosted inside a kubernetes environment. We used bitnami helm chart 8.2.1.
If we connect to an on-premise Replica Set installation of MongoDB 4.2.3, everything is ok. So we assume the problem must be with the configuration of the kubernetes installation. If I try to connect with MongoDB Compass to the kubernetes hosted instance, it worked but there are no other nodes visible in the HOSTS area. Connecting to the on-prem installation, there are all nodes visible.

Using the on-prem installation is not an option, because we want that every of our developers has its own database (and of course the same configuration!).

We installed the Replica set with the following script:

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami

# changing architecture or replica count, you must delete the persistance volume claims, otherwise mongodb starts with the previous configuration.
$values = @"
architecture: replicaset
replicaCount: 2
replicaSetName: testRS

auth:
  enabled: true
  rootPassword: admin

"@;

<# if I add these part to the above values variable, no connection could be established. Neither from MongoDB Compass nor from C# client
externalAccess:
  enabled: true
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
    port: 27017
  autoDiscovery:
    enabled: true

serviceAccount:
  create: true

rbac:
  create: true
#>



if ( (helm list --namespace="infrastructure" --filter="mongodb" -q) -eq "mongodb") {
  $values | helm upgrade mongodb bitnami/mongodb --values - --namespace infrastructure --recreate-pods --version 8.2.1
}
else {
  $values | helm install mongodb bitnami/mongodb --values - --namespace infrastructure --version 8.2.1
}



helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
$values = @"
tcp:
  # MongoDb
  27017: "infrastructure/mongodb-headless:27017"

"@;


if ( (helm list --namespace="default" --filter="ingress-nginx" -q) -eq "ingress-nginx") {
  $values | helm upgrade ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --values - --namespace default
}
else {
  $values | helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --values - --namespace default
}
```

The dotnet core sample application:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace MongoDBReplicaSet {
    class Program {
        static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            // Connecting to an on-premise installation (1 primary, 2 secondary) worked without any problems.
            //var connectionString = "mongodb://root:admin@on-prem:27080/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=testRS&readPreference=primary";

            var connectionString =
                "mongodb://root:admin@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary";

            await SimpleTask(connectionString);
            await Transaction(connectionString);
            Console.WriteLine("done.");
        }


        static async Task SimpleTask(string connectionString) {
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

            var database = client.GetDatabase("TestDB");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<TestData>(nameof(TestData));
            /*
             * Can not connect to the kubernetes hosted replica set. MongoDB Compass and CLI can connect with the same connection string,
             * but in Compass, you don't see the other nodes under the HOSTS label
             *
             * System.TimeoutException: 'A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{
             * Selectors = WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }.
             * Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "ReplicaSet",
             * State : "Connected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }",
             * EndPoint: "Unspecified/localhost:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Connected", ServerVersion: 4.2.8,
             * TopologyVersion: , Type: "ReplicaSetSecondary", WireVersionRange: "[0, 8]" ...
             *
             *
             * if eliminating the replicaset parameter from the connection string, the exception is different:
             * MongoDB.Driver.MongoNotPrimaryException: 'Server returned not master error.', but sometimes it worked.
             * It seems the client connecting by random to the primary and the other time to the secondary?
             */
            await collection.InsertOneAsync(new TestData(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Test1", new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now)));
            Console.WriteLine("done simple task.");
        }


        static async Task Transaction(string connectionString) {
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

            var database = client.GetDatabase("TestDB");

            // the same exception.

            var collection = database.GetCollection<TestData>(nameof(TestData));
            using (var session = await client.StartSessionAsync()) {
                session.StartTransaction();
                try {
                    await collection.InsertOneAsync(new TestData(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Test2", new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now)));

                    await session.CommitTransactionAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    await session.AbortTransactionAsync();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("done transaction.");
        }
    }

    public class TestData {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; private set; }

        public TestData(string id, string name, DateTimeOffset createdAt) {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            CreatedAt = createdAt;
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone a solution for using MongoDB Replica Set inside Kubernetes and accessing it without any exceptions from outside?

I would be very thankful for helping us.

Comment: Start with https://github.com/p-mongo/mongodb-faq#replica-set-node-reachability.

Comment: How MongoDB is exposed in Kubernetes? NodePort, LoadBalancer, ClusterIP + Ingress? This cluster is in cloud or local env?